# No operator matching those operands

Tags: c++

I'm also receiving the 'no operator "<<" matches these operands" error while trying to display the information.

```
    cout << (<- error with these) PrintHex(ASphere.CalcCircumference()) << endl;
```

I looked around and most people state that it's because of a missing #include. However I think I have everything I need to include. (it also doesn't become a problem until I try to display the info from the functions.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
```

My function looks like this.

```
void PrintHex(int InNum)
{
cout << hex << setiosflags (ios_base::showbase) << InNum;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`PrintHex` already invokes `std::cout` internally, so there's no reason to put it inside another `std::cout` call.

```
PrintHex(ASphere.CalcCircumference());
```

That's all you need to do for it to print.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to print the output of a function that returns a `void`, which means *nothing*.

Return something from your function if you want to print anything.

You can either:

- Just call `PrintHex(ASphere.CalcCircumference());` and print from inside it (what you already do)
- Return a `stringstream` or a `string` from your function and later print it with a `cout` call

Answer (score 2):

Just say:

```
PrintHex(ASphere.CalcCircumference());
```

Your function is not suitable to be used with `<<`, since it doesn't return anything.